# Merge a dataframe from dictionary with for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

i have a dictionary (new_dict) with dataframes and dataframes with dates (serie_tiempo), i wanna select one column from each dataframe in *new_dict* and add it to *dates* the index are the same.
in *filelist* are the name of each dataframe in dictionary

```
filelist
aux1=list(range(23))

for i in aux1:
   serie= pd.merge(serie_tiempo,new_dict[filelist[i]][[filelist[i]]], on="time_stamp", how='left')
```

the line in the for loop add the columns i need, but does not keep the columns that add before.
I need a little fix to my for loop and be done. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The `merge` function returns the merged object. You need to use the same object in the loop.

Try this code:

```
for i in aux1:
   serie_tiempo = pd.merge(serie_tiempo,new_dict[filelist[i]][[filelist[i]]], on="time_stamp", how='left')

print(serie_tiempo)
```